# Using TinyButStrong (TBS) to generate a PDF from a DOCX

Tags: php, pdf, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I have used **TBS (TinyButStrong)** for several `PHP` projects to generate `DOCX` or `XLSX` files based on a template.

I am now trying to popular a `DOCX` template with `TBS` and generate a `PDF` at the of the process. It this possible with `TBS`? It doesnt seem like it supports PDF but not sure if someone has found a plugin to help.

Thank you!

Comment: See https://geekalicious.pt/blog/en/php/convert-openxml-opendocumentos-to-pdf-in-php-with-libreoffice

Answer (score 0):

You can use tbs to generate docx or odt (better) and then convert to pdf using [unoconv](http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/unoconv/)

unoconv can run either as a service or as cli

The conversion from docx do not believe can be done directly; you could convert to an intermediate format, such as .doc. In this I have no direct experience.

Using odt you would not have problems ... and you would have a pdf very close if not equal to that generated odt

Comment: Thank you - do you know if there is anything like this for Windows?

Comment: no, I'm sorry.
you can still use Libreoffice directly from the command line.
After generating the odt files, you can create PDF by launching a simple shell command. The parameters can be found here https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters.